# Difference between lmer formulas with duplicate group specific terms for mixed effects models

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

What is the difference between two formulas with multiple grouping for the `lmer` function in R?

Dependent Variable : Salary

Formula1:

```
as.formula(~1 + WorkingHours + (1 + WorkingHours | JobClass1) 
         + Tenure + (1 + Tenure | JobClass1))
```

Formula2:

```
as.formula(~1 + WorkingHours + (1 + WorkingHours | JobClass1)
         + Tenure + (1 + Tenure | JobClass2))
```

here, `JobClass2` = `JobClass1`(exact same columns in the dataset) but only the name of the variable is different.

Will the Salary predictions made by both the models be the same?

Comment: Could you please supply a reproducible example, if not your actual data then some made up data in which all your variables exist?

Comment: I have re-framed the question for better understanding

Comment: it's still a bit hard to understand the context, but if `JobClass2` and `JobClass1` really differ only in their names, the predictions should indeed be identical.  Do you have any reasons to believe they'd be different?  A reproducible example would definitely help.